# why is $\cos C +\sqrt3\sin C = 2\sin( \pi/6 +C)$ in the solution below?

Tags: geometry

Refer to [Prove the inequality $4S \sqrt{3}\le a^2+b^2+c^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362361/prove-the-inequality-4s-sqrt3-le-a2b2c2)

Law of Cosine $c2 = a2 + b2 -2ab \cos C$ 
$\text{Area of Triangle S} = \frac{1}{2} ab \sin C$

$a^2 + b^2 +c^2 -4S\sqrt{3}$
 $= a^2 + b^2 +( a^2 + b^2 -2ab cosC) -4(\frac{1}{2} ab \sin C)\sqrt{3}$
                             $= 2a^2 +2b^2 -2ab \cos C -2\sqrt{3}ab \sin C$
                             $= 2a^2 +2b^2 -2ab[ \cos C +\sqrt{3} \sin C]$
                             $= 2[a^2 + b^2 -ab[ \cos C +\sqrt{3}sin C]]$
this is the step where I’m lost why is $-ab[ cosC +√3 sinC]= -2ab \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} +C\right)$
i.e. why is $\cos C +\sqrt{3} \sin C = 2\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6} +C\right)$ ?
                             $= 2\left[a^2 + b^2 -2ab \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} +C\right)\right]$
the rest is OK

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos C + \sqrt{3}\sin C = 2 \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\cos C + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin C\right) = 2 \left(\sin\dfrac{\pi}{6}\cos C + \cos\dfrac{\pi}{6}\sin C\right).$$