# Weitzenböck Inequality

Tags: inequality

During one development of a proof of the **Weitzenböck Inequality**, I got a problem:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \sqrt{3(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

but before I had:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \sqrt{3(a+b+c)((a+b+c)/3)^3}$$

My question is: how can I go from the second to the first inequality?

Comment: Just expand everything then you will get AM-GM stuff. If you really want to 'use' second inequality, then I will just say to put $a^2, b^2, c^2$ instead of $a, b, c$ in second inequality :)

Comment: The first inequality *is* Weitzenböck's inequality written with Heron's formula for the area. If the question is how to prove it, see for example [Prove the inequality $4S \sqrt{3}\le a^2+b^2+c^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362361/prove-the-inequality-4s-sqrt3-le-a2b2c2?noredirect=1).

Comment: Actually I'd like an answer with AM-GM concepts.

Comment: The second inequality which is true is better than the first for $a,b,c$ sides of a triangle as $((a+b+c)/3)^3\ge (a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)$